# What is the difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(columnname) after joining tables?

Tags: sql

The first code like this

```
SELECT s.name, w.channel, COUNT(*) num_events
FROM accounts a
JOIN web_events w
ON a.id = w.account_id
JOIN sales_reps s
ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.name, w.channel
ORDER BY num_events DESC;
```

The second code like this

```
SELECT s.name, w.channel, COUNT(w.channel) 
FROM web_events w
JOIN accounts a
ON a.id = w.account_id
JOIN sales_reps s
ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.name, w.channel
ORDER BY COUNT(w.channel) DESC
```

Both codes have the same results. But why? What is different from `COUNT(*) num_events` to `COUNT(w.channel)`?

Comment: COUNT(*) will count all the rows in the table, including NULL values. On the other hand, COUNT(column name) will count all the rows in the specified column while excluding NULL values

Comment: see this
https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-count-distinct/#:~:text=As%20you've%20already%20learned,column%20while%20excluding%20NULL%20values.

Comment: Conclusion, there are no w.channel null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL`,then we can  check `MySQL` official document for [**function_count**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count),and will found below

> COUNT(*) is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain NULL values.

> COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])
> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

So `COUNT(w.channel)` will get total records the query fetch and `w.channel` is not null

Answer (score 0):

- COUNT (*) counts all the row
- COUNT (field) counts rows that field value is not NULL

When i say NULL,  i strictly mean NULL. Check below sql

You can see COUNT function counts empty string on postgrsql (empty string is not same as NULL). But in Oracle database empty strings is same as NULL

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 AS a, 'x' AS b, 1 AS c
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS a, 'x' AS b, 1 AS c
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 AS a, 'y' AS b, 1 AS c
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 4 AS a, 'y' AS b, 1 AS c
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 5 AS a, '' AS b, NULL AS c)
SELECT count( * ) AS "count(*)"
     , count( DISTINCT b ) AS "count( distinct something )"
     , count( c ) AS "count (something)"
FROM temp
```

Result on postgresql

```
count(*)       count( distinct something )           count (something)
--------       --------------------------            -----------------
 5                      3                                4
```

Result on oracle

```
count(*)       count( distinct something )           count (something)
--------       --------------------------            -----------------
 5                      2                                4
```